# Bootstrap Validator 1000Hz allow empty

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using this [bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) and I want to know if there is a way to allow an empty field and if there is 1 character or more in this field the validation appears.

For example I have a phone number field and if this field is empty then do not apply the bootstrap validation but if I have 1 or more character in this field then I need to valid this field if the max and min length = 10.

Comment: You really need to ask this question on git-hub - unless someones uses this they won't know

Comment: have a look at `custom` on `options` here -  http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-options

Comment: So there is a regex who do that ?

Comment: I found something. I removed the required attribute and I replaced by this : `"pattern" => "^0[1-6]{1}(([0-9]{2}){4})|((\s[0-9]{2}){4})|((-[0-9]{2}){4})$"`and it seems to be good